# Adding date to Date picker and then bind Date to viewModel in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, data-binding, xamarin.forms, binding, model-binding

What would be the way to achieve this?
I pass date value to the Date of DatePicker and it works but later I want to do Date{Binding Value} in Xaml so the selected date is passed to the setter getter for further SQLite insertion. However as soon as I add Date{Binding Value} the first date that is passed is not being passed.

Comment: Instead of setting the date picker to the date value you want, set the attribute you are binding the date picker to to the date value you want.

Comment: Like Date="{Binding SourceDate}" . But in this way how do I bind further to pass final selected date to the Sqlite? Date="{Binding }" was set to bind to insert to Sqlite method.

Comment: Can you post your code and Xaml?  I'm not quite sure I'm following what you want to do.  The SQLite persistance is really a separate concern from the view -> viewmodel databinding.